# Trying to modify /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory, but getting permission denied even with sudo

Tags: permissions, sudo, ram

I am trying to edit the file `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`, but I'm getting permission denied even if I use `sudo` or switch to root user via `sudo -i` and try to edit using that account. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/82728/overcommitting-memory-on-an-ubuntu-server-9-10-running-on-vmware-fusion-3-0-osx/82752?newreg=127b5dd4f7f44e81bc6792709bff9a29). I was trying to use vim to edit the file while in root user mode, but it turns out you can't do that since the file is virtual. Instead, I used `echo 1 >/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `sudo -i` and then using `echo`, just pipe `echo` to `sudo tee` instead like this:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It heped me..i had the same: MemoryError: Unable to allocate 2.47 GiB for an array with shape (32419, 10243) and data type float64. It worked.

Comment: @lobjc No problem. Also, if you ever need to append to a file (like `echo >>` for example) you can use `tee -a` to add the output to the last line of a file instead.